# Max of symbolic value - Matlab, use in integral equation.

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

I'm studying probability and I have come across some integral equations, where the upper bound of integral is a function $f(x) = \text{max}(g(x), const.)$ for some function $g(x)$.

My problem is with using `solve` in Matlab, which returns the following error:

> Input arguments must be convertible to floating-point numbers.

I tried some Googling – the command `feval(symengine,'max', g(x) , const.)` doesn't help either.

Any ideas about how to tackle this problem? Even very trivial code like

```
K = 5 ;
syms x real
solve(max(K,x)+3 == 10,x);
```

results in error. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you want to do symbolic calculations, I think you need to pass a string as argument to `solve()`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help and even after a bit of googling I haven't found a way to make string argument useful in this situation. However matlab suggested me to use char instead of string, after using char it said exactly the same error message :)

Comment: @flawr: Nope. Unless 5–10 you're using an old version of Matlab.

Comment: @Johny: the issue is not with `solve`, but using symbolic variables with `max`. The max function is [ill-defined for general symbolic math](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102485-why-are-symbolic-variables-not-allowed-when-using-the-functions-max-min-in-the-symbolic-math-toolbox). Is there a reason why you're using symbolic math instead of numerical math?

Comment: Also, in simple cases, you may be able to use piecewise functions to represent max or split your integral into multiple parts. You can try using MuPAD's [`piecewise`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/piecewise.html) from [within Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/call-built-in-mupad-functions-from-the-matlab-command-window.html), but it can be a bit cumbersome: `K=5;` `syms x real;` `solve(feval(symengine,'piecewise','[x<K,K]','[x>=K,x]')+3==10,x)`.

Comment: @horchler : I'm not so skilled in matlab (just obtained faculty's student version few days ago), so I'm not sure if I could use numerical instead of symbolic math. But because my x is unknown parameter, and according to codes on the internet, I also started with syms x. In the above easy example, any way to change it tu numerical?